# How can I join data using a fuzzy match in R?

Tags: r, fuzzy-search

I have some subject and license data and would like to create a column that flags whether the license is an appropriate one given the subject listed. The additional challenge is that some teachers teach multiple subjects, separated by semi-colons and there are several acceptable subjects for each license.

I think I need to incorporate something like grep, but I'm not quite sure how to add this function while also joining the data from two tables.

**Sample code**

Below is an excerpt of my dataframe:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(Subject = c("Spanish Language Arts; I teach all subjects for my students", 
"Math; Science", "Mathematics; ELA", "ELA", "Science;Math;English Language Arts", 
"Spanish Language Arts; I teach all subjects for my students",
 "Math", "Science;Social Studies;Mathematics;English Language Arts", "ELA", 
"English Language Arts"), 
Licensure = c("Content Area - Early Childhood (preK-Grade 3)", 
"Core Subjects (Grades EC-6) 1770", "Mathematics (Grades 7-12) 1706", 
"English Language Arts and Reading (Grades 7-12) 1709", "Core Subjects (Grades EC-6) 1770", 
"English Language Arts and Reading (Grades 7-12) 1709", 
"English Language Arts and Reading (Grades 7-12) 1709", 
"Content Area - Elementary Education (Grades 1-6)", 
"Mathematics (Grades 7-12) 1706", "Content Area - Elementary Education (Grades 1-6)"))
```

Here is the list I created that includes all of the licenses with the acceptable programs underneath each:

```r
lic.subject_index <- list(
  "Content Area - Early Childhood (preK-Grade 3)" = c("I teach all subjects for my students", "Math", "Mathematics", "ELA", "English Language Arts", "Language Arts"),
  "Content Area - Elementary Education (Grades 1-6)" = c("I teach all subjects for my students", "Math", "Mathematics", "ELA", "English Language Arts", "Language Arts"),
  "Core Subjects (Grades EC-6) 1770" = c("I teach all subjects for my students", "Math", "Mathematics", "ELA", "English Language Arts", "Language Arts"),
  "English Language Arts and Reading (Grades 7-12) 1709" = c("ELA", "English Language Arts", "Language Arts"),
  "Mathematics (Grades 7-12) 1706" = c("Math", "Mathematics")
)
```

What I would like to be able to do is create a column that flags whether the subject/license combination is acceptable or not:

```r
ideal.df <- data.frame(Subject = c("Spanish Language Arts; I teach all subjects for my students", 
"Math; Science", "Mathematics; ELA", "ELA", "Science;Math;English Language Arts", 
"Spanish Language Arts; I teach all subjects for my students", "Math", 
"Science;Social Studies;Mathematics;English Language Arts", "ELA", "English Language Arts"), 
Licensure = c("Content Area - Early Childhood (preK-Grade 3)", "Core Subjects (Grades EC-6) 1770", 
"Mathematics (Grades 7-12) 1706", "English Language Arts and Reading (Grades 7-12) 1709", 
"Core Subjects (Grades EC-6) 1770", "English Language Arts and Reading (Grades 7-12) 1709", 
"English Language Arts and Reading (Grades 7-12) 1709", "Content Area - Elementary Education (Grades 1-6)", 
"Mathematics (Grades 7-12) 1706", "Content Area - Elementary Education (Grades 1-6)"), 
flag = c("True", "True", "True", "True", "True", "False", "False", "True", "False", "True"))
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse` and `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(tidyverse)
out <- df1 %>%
       rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
       separate_rows(Subject, sep = ';') %>% 
       stringdist_left_join(
         enframe(lic.subject_index, name = 'Licensure', value = 'Subject') %>% 
              unnest) %>% 
       group_by(rn = as.integer(rn)) %>%
       summarise(ind = any(!is.na(Licensure.y))) %>%
       ungroup %>% 
       pull(ind) %>% 
       mutate(df1, flag = .)
out$flag
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

-checking OP''s ideal output

```
as.logical(ideal.df$flag)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. When I incorporate this code into my full dataset, an error pops up saying: NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments. Is there a way to work around NAs as I still want to see those teachers who don't have a license listed? Sorry for not incorporating NAs into my example - I hadn't thought about it until I ran this code!

Comment: @K.C.  May be you filter the dataset by removing the `NA` (with `is.na`) and then use that  to do the join.

Comment: Thank you. I ideally want to keep the NAs in the dataset, but for my purpose, I can do this filter. When I tried it, your code worked.